# what is the name of distribution similar to von mises distribution

Tags: distributions, circular-statistics, von-mises-distribution

I am wondering whether the following PDF is a named distribution. Over the interval $0< \theta < \pi$, the PDF of the distribution is written as
$$ P(\theta) = \frac{2^{-n/2} k^{n/2} e^{k \cos (\theta )} \sin ^n(\theta )}{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+1}{2} \right) I_{\frac{n}{2}}(k)}. $$

The $n=0$ case of this distribution is similar to von Mises distribution apart from the one difference that the domain of von Mises distribution is normally over $0 < \theta < 2 \pi$.

Is it a named distribution? If yes, can someone point some sources about the properties of this distribution?

Comment: I would say that the Von Mises distribution appears log-concave over the support, provded $k > 0$. It is certainly not normal.

Comment: How did you come up with this?. I have not seen it before, but it seems to be something akin to a circular analogue of the chi-square distribution... So am curious and intrigued.